# Will I really not come off as rude even if I don't say thanks in comments?

Tags: discussion

Will I really not come off as rude even if I don't say thanks in the comments? The comment box prompts me to not write thanks, but I often see people with several 100 reps say thanks in their comments? Is upvoting or checking as solved without saying thanks really enough and is the norm here?

Comment: Thanks in comments are just noise. You don't need to do it, upvote instead.

Comment: Yes it is perfectly the norm to not say thanks here. It's not a continuous chatroom but a question and answer site. Feel free to flag all the other "thanks"-comments as "too chatty" or "obsolete", especially if the answer was accepted anyway.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198669/do-most-question-answerers-prefer-gratitude-or-reputation-more - your upvote does come to the attention of the answerer (though we may not know it's you) and expresses your gratitude

Answer (score 13):

> Will I really not come off as rude even if I don't say thanks in their comments?

Yes.

That's how we do things here.

No thanks needed. If you want to thank an answerer - upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add - I know I'm guilty of having done this since joining...but now having read this question I'll feel comfortable to just upvote now knowing that this is the community culture here. One point though: It could help to have an "introduction" page for members giving them a feel for how the community works

Comment: @Bendy: You mean, like [tour]?

Comment: @AlE.yes along those lines but something that would give new members an idea on the "culture" how to write questions/answers succinctly and that people don't want/expect 'noise' of comments just saying thanks etc